# Problem with some 縮約形

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

I just came across some of the "contracted forms" used in conversations, which I'm not really familiar with. May you help me decoding the ones that I found impossible to understand and to translate them into the more "common" form?

I will explain it better, for example in this sentence: "あしたいちんち、どっか出掛けよっか。", I do understand that どっか is どこか and that 出掛けよっか is 出掛けようか, but I cannot figure out what いちんち means.

I also found: "何すんの", which I believe corresponds to "何するの", but I'm not really sure about it.

The last one that I cannot understand is 買ってこよっか, as in: "何か飲むもんでも、買ってこよっか".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

> あしたいちんち　 >>> 　明日一日 【あしたいちにち】
>
> どっか 　　　　　>>> 　どこか
>
> 出掛けよっか　　 >>> 　出掛けようか  【でかけようか】
>
> 何すんの　　　　 >>> 　何するの  【なにするの】
>
> 飲むもんでも　　 >>> 　飲【の】む物【もの】でも
>
> 買ってこよっか　 >>> 　買【か】ってこようか

The first one いちんち is somewhat rare but there are other words like it which can have similar contractions when certain vowel+consonant combinations occur.

For example おれのうち becoming おれんち.

Answer (score 0):

すんの and ～よっか are extremely common casual contractions of するの and ～ようか.

いちんち, on the other hand, I've never seen before, and to me it looks more like a typo than anything at first glance. Where did you see this? From the context, I would guess it's a contraction of 一日 (いちにち), but I don't think it's a particularly common one.

A little searching suggests that this may actually be a [dialectal word](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1%E3%82%93%E3%81%A1), clearly deriving from 一日 but with slightly different usages depending on the source region.

Comment: I found it in the 新完全マスター ;)

Comment: `いちんち... I've never seen before, and to me it looks more like a typo` `dialectal word` 「いちんち」って、日常会話ではめっちゃ言いますけど。。　文学作品でも見ますし。夏目漱石とかいろいろ。

Comment: そうなんですか？勉強になります！